# How to restore recent files back to their folders?

Tags: macos, icloud, backup, automation

I have recently tried to iCloud backup and I restored local files. But in doing this, accidently I pressed cancelled and local files were not backed up fully.

Luckily, I found my local files in iCloud (archives) which is in recents files. But they are located in files not by folders. I can copy and paste, and bring back to the mac, but need to create every folder. Is there any way to bring recents files back to mac with folders?

The image below shows the recents file which was backed up by iCloud archives. I want them back to be relocated in folders which I created before iCloud backup. I really cannot create every folder and bring each file back in..

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How did you backup to iCloud in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, "Recents" are recently accessed files. I have disabled this function on my system. If you have backed up you drive or some folder(s) to iCloud in some way then I would suspect the using "iCloud Drive" instead of "Recents" could give you the folder structure containing you backed up.

At this point these are just semi-educational guesses as I neither use iCloud for file backup or have "Recents" active.